# URLEncode not working in browser MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url-encoding, urldecode

Hi my encoded URL path I need to pass in browser should be as below

https://localhost:44384/part-lookup/all/gmc/1973/p25%2fp2500+van/base/41l-l6

but browser convert this URL to below path and because of that I get 404 error

https://localhost:44384/part-lookup/all/gmc/1973/p25/p2500+van/base/41l-l6

MY routing path declared is as below

```
routes.MapRoute(
          name: "ShopByCateShopNow",
          url: "part-lookup/{category}/{make}/{year}/{models}/{submodel}/{engine}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ShopNow" }
        );
```

Here sub model actual value is as 'P25/P2500 VAN' and after encoding this value it gets convert to 'p25%2fp2500+van' value due to which it is not redirecting properly and showing 404 error.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%2F` is an HTML path character.  If you want to treat it as data you will have to encode it yourself.  Or create a path that has another level between model and submodel and re-combine them in the controller.

```
routes.MapRoute(
          name: "ShopByCateShopNow",
          url: "part-lookup/{category}/{make}/{year}/{modelprefix}/{modelsuffix}/{submodel}/{engine}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ShopNowPrefixSuffix" }
        );
```

After combining in the controller you can call the same method that maps to your ShopNow action with `models = $"{modelprefix}/{modelsuffix}"` or similar.

Comment: I have multiple routing methods so i need to handle like this for all routings?

Comment: If you have data that includes HTML special characters like `slash` or `?`, yes.  Alternately you can move the parameters to the Query String so you can use name/value pairs but you will lose the REST-fulness of this API.

Comment: I used to "encode" some "special" characters to `&dash;` or `&hyphen;` etc. on my client and "decode" them on the server.  That is a custom encoding scheme and while it worked, I would not recommend it.

Comment: till now I have the issue of slash, do you know some special character which we need to use take care in future in case of url?

Comment: any new idea pls

Comment: change your data so you are not using characters that have special meaning to HTTP.

Comment: I need to use your this approach "I used to "encode" some "special" characters to &dash; or &hyphen; etc. on my client and "decode" them on the server. That is a custom encoding scheme and while it worked, I would not recommend it."

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you can use `Request.Path.ToString()` to get the unadulterated path. This would include `p25%2fp2500+van`, so you can use

```
var url = Request.Path.ToString();
var model = url.Split('/')[4];
```

There is a risk that the index won't be 4 if you access this from other places, or sometimes host the site in subfolders.

Comment: This approach is highly brittle.  If the other slashes are also encoded it would fail unpredictably.  The submodel and following variables would also be incorrect and need to be manually adjusted from the automagically mapped variables.